# Javascript event binding in Microsoft Edge not Working in lightning Components

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, community

Hi i have a problem with Microsoft Edge and lightning Component, the thing here is that i build a lightning component and works fine on all other browsers but when i test it on Microsoft Edge it shows me this error:

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback()[Unabled to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference] Failing descriptor: {markup://aura.html}
```

I searched about that error on salesforce forums and no one has the solution, then i found that that error is due to a javascript syntax error. I changed the syntax of the tag that has the 'onclick event' from:

```
<button onclick="{! c.someAction }">Action</button>
```

to:

```
<button onClick="{! c.someAction }">Action</button>
```

You can see that only changed the 'c' to upper case and the error is not showing anymore, but anyways it doesnt do anything.

PD. On my controller code i only have a console.log.

Comment: Issue already being discussed here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159917/onclick-not-working-in-lightning-components-in-edge